# postorder traversal function calling error

Tags: python

Definition for a binary tree node.

```
class TreeNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
         self.left = left
       self.right = right
class Solution:
    def postorder(self,root,a):
        if not root:
            return
        postorder(root.left)
        postorder(root.right)
        a.append(root.val)
    def postorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
        a=[]
        postorder(root,a)
        return a
```

It shows postorder function is not defined and gives a name error. Can anyone find the problem?

Comment: Please include the full traceback and the code you use to init the classes.

Comment: use `self` keyword, while calling the function from same class like `self.postorder()`

Answer (score 2):

The problem it's the way you're calling the `postorder` function within the Solution class. You need to use `self` to call the function because `postorder` is a bound method of the Solution class:

```py
from typing import List, Optional

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Solution:
    def postorder(self, root, a):
        if not root:
            return
        self.postorder(root.left, a)
        self.postorder(root.right, a)
        a.append(root.val)
    
    def postorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
        a = []
        self.postorder(root, a)
        return a
```